# Как сделать чтобы в js input time форме 0 автоматом подтягивался если указываем менее 10 часов?

Tags: javascript, время, inputmask

Вот код формы

```
HTMLElement.prototype.timeMask = function() {
    let mask = new IMask(this, {
        mask: 'H:M',
        lazy: false,
        placeholderChar: '_',
        blocks: {
            H: {
                mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
                from: 0,
                to: 23,
                maxLength: 2,
                overwrite: true,
            },
            M: {
                mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
                from: 0,
                to: 59,
                maxLength: 2,
            }
        }
    })

    mask.type = 'time'
    this.mask = mask
}
```

Возможно нужно где-то ещё посмотреть код, если так подскажите. Форма не принимает первую цифру начинающуюся НЕ с 0, 1 или 2, но мне нужно чтобы если мы вводим ранее 10 часов первый ноль в форме автоматом проставлялся, подскажите добрые разработчики, как это сделать?